# Find a keyword occurred today using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to find All the ORA Errors in my log.txt file that has occurred today using batch program. I am not good with Batch so not able to add date time filter with my code below.

```
@echo off
findstr /m "ORA-" Alert.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo There is an ORA Error in Alert File!
)
```

Errors in file:

```
2019-10-14T00:43:40.497493+01:00
Errors in file C:\R2DATABASE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\diag\rdbms\r2\r2\trace\r2_j000_11628.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "R2"."R3NOTIFICATION_160328336632"
ORA-06550: line 1, column 763:
PLS-00201: identifier 'R3NOTIFICATION_PKG.GENERATENOTIFICATIONFORR3' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 763:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2019-10-14T00:43:42.029005+01:00
Errors in file C:\R2DATABASE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\diag\rdbms\r2\r2\trace\r2_j001_2524.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "R2"."R3NOTIFICATION_160328336632"
ORA-06550: line 1, column 763:
PLS-00201: identifier 'R3NOTIFICATION_PKG.GENERATENOTIFICATIONFORR3' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 763:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Date time format - `2019-10-14T00:43:40.497493+01:00`

Comment: I have added few lines of my text file, thank you for responding @Compo

Comment: I just need to print all the ORA-* Errors which has occured in this text file with today's date
@Compo

Comment: click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58449178/edit) please

Comment: No, it is as it is in question; newline

Comment: Well, then just count the number of lines until first occurrence of date, then run a loop, skip the number of lines up to the date, then count instances from there of `ORA-`

Comment: Not being good is no excuse for not trying anything, so please [edit] the question to share a [mcve] of your coding attempts and precisely describe the issues you are facing! Also take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask]!

Comment: I have tried many ways, hit and trial, but I am not getting the desired output. The requirement is way too much and what I am asking here is just a small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based upon the advice from Gerhard's comment. It should output the lines from today which begin with `ORA-` and with a description beginning with `error`.

```bat
@Set "Var="
@For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In (
    '^""%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" /NJH /L "\|" Null^"'
)Do @If Not Defined Var Set "Var=%%A-%%B-%%CT"
@Set "Line="
@For /F "Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /NLB "%Var%" "Alert.txt"'
)Do @If Not Defined Line Set /A Line=%%A-1&GoTo :GetLines
:GetLines
@If Defined Line More +%Line% "Alert.txt"|"%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /LB "ORA-"
@Pause
```

Comment: Thank you @Compo, However, can I print the entire ORA error at least the ORA-**** in my output, basically, the output of findstr(all the ORA Errors) and their count ?

Comment: Of course you can, I provided the answer above to match `ORA Errors`, I took that to mean lines beginning with `ORA-` and with a description beginning with the string `error`. Just change `/RIC:"^ORA-[0-9]*:\ error"` to `/LB "ORA-"`. I've updated my answer to suit.